# Opening Odata Data Source Throws file(con, "r") Error

Tags: r, odata

I am using R Version 0.99.902 to analyze data on **PA Open Data**. 
Here is one of the datasets on that site:

https://data.pa.gov/Infrastructure-and-Development/State-Structurally-Deficient-Bridges-Let-CY-2015-2/we8x-iva4

Here's what I've tried:

```
library(Odata)
```

bridges.raw<-retrieveData("https://data.pa.gov/Infrastructure-and-Development/State-Structurally-Deficient-Bridges-Let-CY-2015-2/we8x-iva4")

I've also tried:

```
bridges.raw<-retrieveData("https://data.pa.gov/OData.svc/we8x-iva4")
```

Each command returns the following error:
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

Any thoughts on how to proceed? Any successes using R and Odata to tap PA Open Data?

Thanks!

Comment: Current R version is 3.3.2. You may be referring to Rstudio, which is "just" an IDE and has basically not influence on the functionality of R itself. Regarding your question, the docs for the `?retrieveData` function state that it needs to refer to "`$format=json` as parameter".

Comment: Thanks Roman! With the $format=json parameter in place I get the same error. In addition, "HTTP status was '400 Bad Request' "